# Maximum height of radical of an ideal in a Noetherian ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am self-studying commutative algebra and basic algebraic geometry. At the time of solving some problems, I got stuck on the following.

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring. $\mathcal{I}$ be an ideal of $R$ which can be generated by $n$ elements. Then can we conclude that $\operatorname{ht}(\sqrt{\mathcal{I}})$ is less than or equal to $n$?

Can we somehow use Krull's height theorem?

Thank you. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: By the way, it seems you have not been upvoting answers to your questions this year. Do you not believe that they are useful? (This is the tooltip language - when you mouse over the upvote arrow, you get "[t]his answer is useful".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Krull's height theorem is a good tool to use here, you're just missing a little argument. Recall that the definition of the height of an ideal is the minimum of the heights of the prime ideals $P\supset I$, and note that any prime ideal containing $I$ must also contain $\sqrt{I}$: if $i \in \sqrt{I}$, then $i^n\in I$ for some $i$, and $i^n\in P$ implies $i\in P$ by the definition of a prime ideal. Therefore the prime ideals containing $I$ and the prime ideals containing $\sqrt{I}$ are the exact same prime ideals, so Krull's height theorem gives the result.

One geometric interpretation of this is that the topological spaces $V(I)$ and $V(\sqrt{I})$ inside $\operatorname{Spec} R$ are the same, and the height of these ideals is the common Krull dimension of this topological space.